# Show all inherited tags in format %T, in org-agenda-prefix-format

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

The documentation says that `%T` shows the tag of the item. However the documentation states:

```
%T   the last tag of the item (ignore inherited tags, which come first)
```

How can I get **All** the tags (inherited and direct) to be displayed with `%T`? Just like how they usually show up at the right of the item:

```
:TAG1:TAG2::MY_TAG:
```

I know that I could put the tags at the right, but I don't want that. I am explicitly removing them.

```
(setq org-agenda-remove-tags-when-in-prefix 'prefix)
```

Comment: I don't see a way of doing that. This is buried in a couple of places in the code: in `org-compile-prefix-fomrat` which pre-cooks the `org-agenda-prefix-format` string into a more efficient structure that will allow quicker processing of all the agenda items, and in `org-agenda-format-item` which is called to process each item on the agenda. The relevant processing in the latter is in `org-agenda.el:L7228ff` for the first part (getting rid of the tags at the end of the item) and `org-agenda.el:L7278` for adding the last tag to the item in the place you specified in `org-agenda-prefix-format`.

Comment: The line numbers are approximate of course: they are the ones in my copy of the code which is ` Org mode version 9.5.2 (release_9.5.2-409-gc1b034)`.

Comment: My final target is to use the tags string at the left of the items in the agenda-view. Perhaps there is an alternative approach to this?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you want to do. I don't see an alternative though: the `org-compile-prefix-format` function will have to be changed to provide an evaluator that provides the whole string of all the tags rather than the last tag. BTW, it'll probably destroy the alignment of your items completely.